# Pandas encoding for binary data to_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding

I am using pandas(0.17.1) and have a data frame containing some binary data(for images)

Trying to write this to a csv I am encountering issues with encoding. encoding="utf-8" which I use for most frames I am saving results in a unicode decode error but leaving that out gives an Ascii error. Is there a specific value I should be sending to encoding to allow for storing of this binary data?

python 2.7.10 is the version being used

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `base64`, but I think you need to encode the data before `.to_csv()` like so:

```
import base64
encodedImage.value = encodedImage.value.apply(lambda x: base64.b16encode(x))
encodedImage.value.to_csv()
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html).

Comment: Did this help after all?